# vertical-align image within overflow:hidden div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align an image vertically within a div with overflow set to hidden so that the container has the same height for each post. I have tried a lot of other solutions, but it is not working with the overflow element. Anybody? This is my CSS code so far:

```
.featured-image-blog{
  height: 220px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.featured-image-blog img{
  height: auto;    
  width: 600px;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="featured-image-blog">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('featured-image'); ?>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are yuo able to change the html?

Comment: What is your query? I am still confuse.

Comment: @Pete Yes, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vertical alignment has always been a pain in legacy HTML and stuff I suggest you give the div:

```
position: relative;
```

And give the img:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(0, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
```

That should do it..

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, this works! But will it also work in the older IE browsers? I guess not, right?

Comment: Yes.. it works on IE >= 9. for older browsers you can fix it with javascript and paddings. or alternatively use a table and a td since the vertical-align is supported in table cells.. but I don't recommend this at all..

Comment: Thanks, according to my Analytics statistics that's currently around 5% of IE < 9 visitors, just a minor group. I'll go with this one!

Comment: I do that usually.. review analytics and make the trade-off.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `vertical-align` `CSS` property?

Give this a try:

```
.featured-image-blog img{
  height: auto;    
  width: 600px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It should align it to the middle of the parent container.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align